# Random fills in PCB in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I have this red hatched line around a button and Eagle shows an error for this. What is this error?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dimension error means something is too close to something else. In this case it looks like your silkscreen is too close to your hole (shown by the rectangular outline). You can either cut back the silkscreen, ignore the error (most fab houses won't lay silkscreen over holes anyway, they'll cut it back themselves), or move the component (if the hole is not part of it).

EDIT: I take that back, it is not the silkscreen layer. OlinLanthrop is correct in that it is not the silkscreen, but he is not correct in which layer is the issue. I should have looked a bit more carefully. The error box shows what layer the error is on -- #1, which is the top layer. This suggests that the red trace (on the top layer) is too close to the hole--Not the bottom layer (blue) or the silkscreen. Notice the hashed area is also red, meaning the conflict is with the "red" (or top) layer, if I remember correctly.

I expect if you neck the trace down a bit, or adjust your rules to meet your fab house's abilities, your error will go away (if the trace is not in violation of the manufacturer's rules).

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the silkscreen. I don't know how you thought that since the hashed area isn't between the hole and the silkscreen.  The clearance issue is clearly between the hole and the blue trace.

Comment: Need to change the ```Copper/Dimension``` setting on the ```Distance``` tab of the DRC.

Answer (score 3):

The DRC check found a error, and is showing you where it is.

Note that the description is "dimension".  In this case it means something is too close to something else.  The red hashed area is showing you the conflict zone so you can look at what's on either side and decide whether they need to be moved farther apart, or perhaps the distance setting are set too large.

In this case it's obvious from the picture that the blue trace is too close to the hole on the right side.  Note the larger gap between hole and copper on the left side, with no hatched area indicating a problem.

It's strange that the keepout area around the hole didn't automatically eat into the blue trace.  This points to a process problem on your end.  You may have manually tried to route something that you shouldn't have, and the system thinks it has no flexibitly to change it.

### Added:

Upon closer examination, I think Derstrom is right.  It's not the blue trace, but the red one causing the problem.  Since the red trace is farther away from the hole, it seems its clearance in the net class is set large, and the hole is too close for that clearance.

Check to make sure you really need the clearance specified in the net class for the red trace.  If you do, then you have to move the hole and/or the trace.

Comment: Looks like that's a ground plane on the bottom (blue) layer.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is an optical illusion. The distance between the hole and the blue pour on the right is the same as the distance between the hole and the red pour on the left. The hatched area simply makes it look like a smaller distance. I expect the clearance rules for traces are set so that his hole falls within the "keep-out" area of the trace.

Comment: @derst: Yeah, I think you're right.